# How to select a DOM element that was passed in as a parameter with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have

```
<span onclick="show(this)">foobar</span>

function show(theSpan) {
    ....... //select the span here
}
```

How could I use Jquery selector to select the span? I tried $(theSpan) but it doesn't work. I want to select it as a Jquery object so that I can apply attr() to it.

Thanks!

Comment: what you mean by 'doesnt work'. does it throw any error?

Comment: whats the attr you want from the span?

Comment: yes $(theSpan).attr('test, '123'); works fine.

Comment: problem lies somewhere else, vote for delete thanks all. sorry for confusion

Comment: thought it was the selector not working, turned out to be something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(theSpan).attr('test, '123');` works fine.

Your problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no atribute in your element but just to put you an example, suppose that you got this:

```
<span id="spTest" onclick="show(this);">foobar</span>​
```

This is the way you could get an atribute like the id:

```
var id = $(theSpan).attr('id'); //outputs: spTest
```

But I am not sure what you mean in your question, maybe you need the value, so this is the way  to get it:

```
var spanValue = $(theSpan).html(); //outputs: foobar
```

Also, If are you trying to set an id to that element, you can do the following:

```
//Set the id
$(theSpan).attr('id', 'theSpan');
//Store the value from your element by the new id
var spanValue = $('#theSpan').html();
//Do what you want at this point
alert(spanValue); //outputs: foobar
```